# How to calculate cooccurrences on a set of texts with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm collecting newspapers articles on ElasticSearch. I would like to find the most recurrents words for a topic. It is possible with ElasticSearch? I make an example to explain better:
I search for Donald Trump in my collection and I find 2000 articles. Is it possible to parse all these articles, collecting all the tokens, and sorting them for the count?

Something like this:

```
 {Donald Trump {USA: 200 times on 150 docs}, {presidential: 180 times on 130 docs},{Clinton: 150 times on 100 docs},{republican: 120 times on 110 docs}, etcetera...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a "terms" aggregation will indeed give you the data you described, you might want to look into the [significant terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html) to get more insightful data.

Given your example, a search for "trump" will give you "USA" as the most common term, but that will be the case for most other queries in your "candidates" data set. A significant term aggregation would probably show "republican" as being a much more significant characteristic of the subset described by your query.